# Localhost:3000 error when server is running using RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Whenever I start the server and go to localhost:3000, this error shows up. I've already allowed the firewall settings in my mac, but this error just keeps showing up.

This same thing happens when I tried installing and running on my friend's laptop.

HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR
[link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqiGO.png)

Comment: What is the error you encountered?

Comment: When i go to localhost:3000, it shows a bunch on errors in words. Errors ing ruby mine must have a red banner on top, but in my case, it just shows words and symbols. (Reuploading the screenshot of what shows up)

Comment: I edited the post and added the link to the screenshot of the error

Comment: I added answer below. Let me know if there is still an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot. I tells that you don't have a database scheduler_development. To resolve this, run:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```